# Devise - Force JSON Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, devise

How can I force the response to JSON on Devise?

When my controllers require authentication with

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

the response is only in JSON if I post JSON data.
But I want Devise to respond always in JSON for some controllers and actions.

EDIT

I am using

```
:token_authenticatable
```

so I am passing auth_token for every call:

```
curl --data "token=xyzHtPAFGuAuFiVWsxsZ&receipt=adsfadsfsdfdsf" http://0.0.0.0:3000/user/receipt
```

But the response is a HTML redirect when the token is incorrect

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

I'd like that response to be a JSON

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question but this might be what you are looking for. Just add respond_to inside your controller like:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tryed that, but the response stills a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the **content type** of the desired response.

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -H "Accept:application/json \
     -d "token=xyzHtPAFGuAuFiVWsxsZ&receipt=adsfadsfsdfdsf" \
      http://0.0.0.0:3000/user/receipt
```

Please have a look at the man page of *curl* for further parameters.